# Jenkins Github plugin doesn't set status

Tags: github, jenkins, groovy

I'm trying to set a github status from a Jenkins job. Jenkins returns a

```
[Set GitHub commit status (universal)] SUCCESS on repos [] (sha:9892fbd) with context:ci/jenkins/tests
```

... but the status isn't set when I query it with the REST API later.

There's the groovy code:

```
def getCommitHash() {
    sh(script: """
git rev-parse HEAD
""", returnStdout: true).trim()
}


def setCountTestLocation(String location) {
    url = "https://<internal github>/<org>/<repo>"
    commitHash = getCommitHash()
    print(url)
    print(commitHash)
    step([
            $class: "GitHubCommitStatusSetter",
            reposSource: [$class: "ManuallyEnteredRepositorySource", url: url],
            contextSource: [$class: "ManuallyEnteredCommitContextSource", context: "ci/jenkins/tests"],
            statusBackrefSource: [$class: "ManuallyEnteredBackrefSource", backref: location],
            errorHandlers: [[$class: "ChangingBuildStatusErrorHandler", result: "UNSTABLE"]],
            commitShaSource: [$class: "ManuallyEnteredShaSource", sha: commitHash],
            statusResultSource: [ $class: "ConditionalStatusResultSource", results: [[$class: "AnyBuildResult", message: "Tests here!", state: "SUCCESS", location: location]] ]
        ]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You repository hasn't been updated as it seems that repos were not properly set.
Plugin still reports success as it properly completed its run, but repo list is empty as evident in your message `SUCCESS on repos []`.

Answer (score 1):

This issue can occur if you have not set up a "GitHub Server" config under the global Jenkins configs:

Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> GitHub

You can find more details on how to set up a server configuration under the "Automatic Mode" section of the GitHub Plugin documentation:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin#GitHubPlugin-AutomaticMode%28Jenkinsmanageshooksforjobsbyitself%29

Answer (score 0):

After much pain with the same issue and plugin, here is a fix not for this particular plugin, but rather a workaround that does not require a plugin and still solves the issue, using `curl`. You can add the following to your pipeline:

```
post {
  success {
    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'your_credentials_id', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {
      sh 'curl -X POST --user $USERNAME:$PASSWORD --data  "{\\"state\\": \\"success\\"}" --url $GITHUB_API_URL/statuses/$GIT_COMMIT'
    }
  }
  failure {
    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'your_credentials_id', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {
      sh 'curl -X POST --user $USERNAME:$PASSWORD --data  "{\\"state\\": \\"failure\\"}" --url $GITHUB_API_URL/statuses/$GIT_COMMIT'
    }
  }
}
```

Where the `GITHUB_API_URL` is usually constructed like so, for example in the `environment` directive:

```
environment {
   GITHUB_API_URL='https://api.github.com/repos/organization_name/repo_name'
}
```

The `credentialsId` can be created and obtained from `Jenkins -> Credentials`